# SublimeText3 open header/source

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use sublimetext3 to program C++.

I use multiple window splits with multiple  files open.

Sometimes I use alt+o hotkey / switch_file command to open the associated header/source file.

If I hit switch_file command and the matching header/source is already open in the same sub window split, it will jump to that tab instead of reopening the file.

But if I have a header open in one sub window split, and the source open in another sub window split, and I do switch_file command, it will open another copy of the file in the currently focused window.

Is there a way that I can set it to jump to the file even if it needs to focus another window split?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to establish this is to change the `switch_file` command.
Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) and type `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, select `Default` and then open `switch_file`.

In line `41` just change

```py
self.window.open_file(new_path, flags = sublime.FORCE_GROUP)
```

to

```py
self.window.open_file(new_path)
```

and save the file. This will not overwrite the existing file (which is in a zip folder), but create a file, which shadows the original file.

Comment: Works a treat. I think this should be the default ST behaviour. In a 2 pane layout with the source file open in one and the header file open in the other `alt+o` source/header switching ceases to be useful unless this change is made. It's going to be a time saver for me. Thanks r-stein.